# Homomorphic image of a complex algebraic torus is an algebraic torus

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm having troubles of proving that if $T: {(\mathbb{C}^{*})}^{n} \rightarrow {(\mathbb{C}^{*})}^{s}$, is a homomorphism between algebraic tori, then the homomorphic image $\thinspace$$T({\mathbb{C}^{*}}^{n})$$\thinspace$ is again a torus.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T\colon (\Bbb C^*)^n \to (\Bbb C^*)^s$ is a morphism of algebraic tori, there are unique vectors $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in \Bbb Z^s$ such that
$$ T(t) = t_1^{a_1}\cdots t_n^{a_n},$$
where for $z \in \Bbb C$ and $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_d) \in \Bbb Z^d$, we set $z^u = (z^{u_1}, \ldots, z^{u_d})$. Let $N$ be the $\Bbb Z$-span of the $a_i$'s. Since $\Bbb Z^s$ is a finitely generated torsion free abelian group, so is $N$. Hence, $N\cong \Bbb Z^d$ for some d. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_d$ be a free $\Bbb Z$-basis of $N$. Then (prove this!)
$$ \operatorname{im}T = \{t_1^{v_1}\cdots t_d^{v_d} \mid t_i \in \Bbb C^*\}.$$
Define a function $F\colon (\Bbb C^*)^d \to \operatorname{im} T$ by
$$ F(t) = t_1^{v_1}\cdots t_d^{v_d}.$$ This is certainly a morphism of algebraic tori, and it's onto by the above. This, all that remains to show is that it's one-one. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Avi thank you for your response! I have one question though, I can understand that we can "decompose" $T$ as a product of one-parameter subgroups, that is homomorphisms of the form $\phi : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow {\mathbb{C}^{*}}^{n}$, are these $t_{i}$ the same thing?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris yup.

Comment: ok then! Think, I got this! Thank you again!

Comment: One more question, where does this $d$ come from?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris It's the rank of $N$.

Comment: It's not quite true that $F$ is one-to-one. Take for example $n = s = 1$, $T(t) = t^k$ for $k > 1$. Then $F = T$, but the map is not one-to-one. However, one can show that the kernel is finite, which is enough to show $(\mathbf{C}^*)^d \simeq \mathrm{im} T$.